# Multilevel dynamic linear models in R

Tags: kalman-filter, state-space-models, dynamic-regression, dlm, bsts

I am interested in fitting a *multilevel* bayesian structural time series with a hierarchical structure of the dynamic regression coefficients. The reason I want to do this is is that I have a number of dynamic regressors and many of them are related at a grouping level (imagine many prices for each category of good, with a number of categories).

In short, I am interested in fitting a model something like the following (I'm not sure this specification is perfectly nailed down, so if you know what I'm trying to specify and this has errors, please edit!):

$$Y_t = X\beta_t + v_t$$
$$\beta_t = Z\Delta_{t} + w_t$$
$$\Delta_t = \Delta_{t-1} + u_t$$

Where the X are the "varying intercepts" / category-level coefficients, so to speak, and the Z are the good-level coefficients.

The software that I typically use to estimate bayesian structural time series is `bsts` in `R`. I have gone through as much of the `dlm` documentation as I can understand but I don't think that something like this is possible.